# Sorting with partial pairwise orderings

Tags: sorting

I have n elements that I need to sort. I don't know there exact value of each element and I only have partial information on their pairwise order. For example, I have the following data:

| Element1 | Element2 | order |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 1 |
| B | C | 1 |
| C | D | 1 |
| D | A | -1 |

In this case, I know A is smaller than B, B is smaller than C, but I don't have the information in my data on the relationship between A and C.

What I need is a sorted list of all the elements, assuming this partial pairwise order information can recover the full relationship. Is there any efficient way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: What technology are you trying to solve this in?

Comment: @LajosArpad Preferably in Python but I'm open to other languages as well.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can apply back-tracking. You want to compare **a** and **b**. So, let's loop all elements that contain **a** and see whether value is 1 or -1. Then, loop all elements that were paired with **a**, see whether the value changes (in which case you ignore this path) and if not, go on. You repeat this process until you reach **b** from **a** as your starting point with `value` being consistent.

Avoid cycles while doing so.

You can apply recursion, but I strongly advise you to use a stack and build that stack up with the items you already have.

When you find a consistent path from **a** to **b**, you stop your algorithm, assuming that the rule-set does not consider self-contradictions.